# React-Native Flat List columns number depending on screen orientation

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to change numColumns of FlatList on Orientation change.(e.g. For portrait: numColumns=2 and landscape numColumns=3)

But for each Item in list it takes different width
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X88Ap.png)

I have tried using Dimensions to change width of each item dynamically

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  Dimensions.addEventListener("change", this.updateStyles);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", this.updateStyles);
}
updateStyles = dims => {
  this.setState({
    viewMode: dims.window.width > 400 ? "landscape" : "portrait"
  });
};
```

For Styling

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  listContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  landscapeListItem: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 3 - 20
  },
  portraitListItem: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 2 - 10
  }
});
```

So it looks like this:

- in [Landscape Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X88Ap.png)
- after changing orientation to [Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X88Ap.png)
- on [Reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X88Ap.png)

Reloading screen applies width correctly. But I don't want to reload it.
It should set the width on Orientation Change.

Does anyone knows how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Approach detech Device Oriantation and set `numColumns`.

```
 <View onLayout={this._onLayout}>
        {/* Subviews... */}
 </View>
```

Handle event store orientation on in `state`

```
_onLayout(event){
  const { width, height } = event.layout; //somewhat similar object
  const orientation = (width > height) ? 'LANDSCAPE' : 'PORTRAIT';
  this.setState({orientation})
 }
```

Now `FlatList`

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={this.state.orientation == "LANDSCAPE" ? 3 :2}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```